# there is lots of white space after footer

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am creating an html page with two iframes. Left frame will be for navigational purpose and right one will display actual content. But there is a lot of space remained below the footer. How can i remove it?

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Orion ERP Help</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Orion Logo">
</div>
<div id="navi">
<iframe id="menu" src="menu.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="frame">
<iframe id="content" name="content" src="about.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   © 2013 Intelligent ERP. All right reserved.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 17%;
 }

#header {
background-color: #f8651c;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 130px;
}

#logo {
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
padding: 0;
}


#menu {
position: absolute;
background-color: #f6f6f6;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 17%;
border: 0;
border-right: 2px solid #a2a2a2;
}


#frame {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

#content {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

#footer {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-size: 70%;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
width: 83%;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the padding on the body class

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }
```

Comment: it is there to hold the image in its place, without the 17% padding image will get displaced

Comment: @lichborne This answer is valid. You can add padding and margins to your images to fix them instead of applying padding to other elements.

Comment: you are adding a 17% margin on the bottom of your body, this is why you have lots of white space. You should apply the margin on the image or use another technique else i believe you wont get rid of the space

Comment: never mind....u showed me the way...thank you very much...actually i have to remove teh body padding and add it to teh related div...it worked!!