# Space at the footer in HTML

Tags: html, footer

I have a little problem , I have a large white bar below the footer ..

Code: http://pastebin.com/Bi1e65ve  (The image and the original code is on the pastebin)

Thanks !

Comment: What is that little problem ?

Comment: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/142599Sanstitre.jpg

Space after footer

Comment: [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18274474/4290096)

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that you removed any margin from CSS of the class "row" or "col-md-12" or of the link from the footer, the single explaination is that because your page is not full-height sized, it does look like it has a white bar below the footer.

Try adding some content to see if the footer goes down or remains fixed in this position.

If it goes down and you want it to be fixed at the bottom of the page, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805590/css-sticky-footer) to make your footer sticky.